# JavaScript | Sum of number of digits issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, numbers, integer

I was solving one puzzle on counting no of digits in a number. Below is the code:

```
 function countDigits(n) {
 console.log(n);
 let count = 0;
 while (n > 0) {
     let d = n % 10;
     count += d;
     n = Math.floor(n / 10);
 }
 return count; }
```

Most of the text cases gets passed except when no. Of digits in input exceeds 17.

Test Case:

- n = `3546630947312051453014172159647935984478824945973141333062252613718025688716704470547449723886626736`

  Expected: 446

  Getting: 380
- n = `35466309473120515`

  Expected: 64

  Getting: 65

After going through some posts online, I came to know that JavaScript will truncate values if number exceeds 17 digits, for an instance:

```
var a = 35466309473120515
console.log(a) // a => 35466309473120516
```

To resolve this issue in their API Twitter sends tweed id in string instead of number. More details [here](http://2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html).

But in my case I don't have any control over input value. If value exceeds input range (>17), as I convert it to string.

Kindly let me know how can I resolve this.

Comment: maybe you have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: Your input needs to be a string to have the correct sum of digits.

Comment: with input type string , it would work . Is there any possible solution apart from it without converting input to string as I have no control over it

Comment: @Bhupendra then it will break after MAX SAFE Integer.

Answer (score 0):

numbers in javascript are stored on 64 bits : 53 bits for integer value + 11 bits for mantissa:

Hence, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER === 9007199254740991 is the greatest integer you can use without loss of precision.

if your input value is a string, you could simply

1. check it contains only digits with a regex
2. get length of your string

edit: post title is *counting number of digits* but your code is actually **summing** the number of digits. What do you actually want ?